# Strongswan site-to-site VPN connected/established but can't ping server

Tags: ipsec, site-to-site-vpn, strongswan

I need to create site-to-site VPN with one server (Not on "strong swan").
I did everything by this article https://blog.ruanbekker.com/blog/2018/02/11/setup-a-site-to-site-ipsec-vpn-with-strongswan-and-preshared-key-authentication/

```
  config setup
        uniqueids=no
        charondebug="cfg 2, dmn 2, ike 2, net 0"

conn %default
        ikelifetime=86400s
        keylife=3600s
        #rekeymargin=3m
        reauth=yes
        rekey=yes
        rekeyfuzz=0%
        keyingtries=0
        dpdaction=none
        authby=psk

conn ToACB
        authby=secret
        keyexchange=ikev1
        left=188.77.64.128
        leftsubnet=10.133.78.0/24
        leftid=188.77.64.128
        leftfirewall=yes
        right=82.11.134.146
        rightsubnet=10.3.1.0/24
        rightid=82.11.134.146
        #type=tunnel
        ike=aes256-sha-modp1536!
        esp=aes256-sha-modp1536!
        aggressive=no
        auto=start





 sudo cat /etc/ipsec.secrets
# This file holds shared secrets or RSA private keys for authentication.

# RSA private key for this host, authenticating it to any other host
# which knows the public part.

188.77.64.128 82.11.134.146 : PSK "test77"


     ifconfig        
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
            inet 188.166.64.128  netmask 255.255.192.0  broadcast 188.166.127.255
            inet6 fe80::e8ec:8bff:fe55:79db  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
            ether ea:ec:8b:55:79:db  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
            RX packets 18737  bytes 82207417 (82.2 MB)
            RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
            TX packets 16074  bytes 1375834 (1.3 MB)
            TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

    lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
            inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
            inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
            loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
            RX packets 144  bytes 11958 (11.9 KB)
            RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
            TX packets 144  bytes 11958 (11.9 KB)
            TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I have not any NAT rules configured, like MASQUERADE

Answer (score 0):

does the IKE SA come up in the first instance? Probably not.

If not then perform tcpdump on terminating interface to see if packets are arriving.

if this is the case and there is some kind of failed negotiation, then you can check /var/log/ or /var/log/pluto and post what you find there